# How to recover the color to previous status?

Tags: functions

I wrote a function to show some special characters with red color:

```
function! ShowChar()
    set list
    set listchars=tab:→\ ,space:·,nbsp:␣,eol:¶
    highlight SpecialKey ctermfg=blue ctermbg=red guifg=blue guibg=red
endfunction
map <f5> :call ShowChar()<CR>
```

When to press `f5`, the characters -- `tab`, `space`, `nbsp`, `eol` will be shown with red color, now I want to design a new function key `f6`, when to press `f6` after pressing `f5`, all the special characters will be shown as previous status, not with red color.
Should I write a new function which called by `f6`?

Comment: Can you create two highlighting groups `SpecialKeyWarning` and `SpecialKeyNormal` and use [`:h :highlight-link`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3Ahighlight-link)? In your vimrc you link `SpecialKey` to `SpecialKeyNormal`, in `ShowChar()` you link it to `SpecialKeyWarning` and when you're done you link again to `SpecialKeyNormal`?

Comment: What statox is driving at is there isn’t really a good way to “save” the old highlight value... it’s whatever is defined by the colorscheme. You could try just doing `execute 'colorscheme' g:colors_name`

Comment: Yup definitely not a good way to save the value set from the colorscheme indeed, it was just a way to avoid playing with highlighting commands output. But reloading the whole colorscheme as Ben suggests might be a better idea.

Comment: one can use redir with output to variable, parse, save and then restore it

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use `termguicolors`:

```
if has("termguicolors")
  set termguicolors
endif
```

You can use this to store the colors of the `SpecialKey` group each time your colorscheme changes:

```
augroup SaveSpecialKeyColors
  au!
  au ColorScheme,VimEnter *
        \ let g:specialkey_fg = synIDattr(hlID('SpecialKey'), "fg#") |
        \ let g:specialkey_bg = synIDattr(hlID('SpecialKey'), "bg#")
augroup end
```

And a function to toggle:

```
set listchars=tab:→\ ,space:·,nbsp:␣,eol:¶

function! SpecialKeyToggle()
  if &list == ""
    set list
    highlight SpecialKey guifg=blue guibg=red
  else
    exe "highlight SpecialKey guifg= " g:specialkey_bg "guibg= " g:specialkey_bg
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <f6> :call SpecialKeyToggle()<CR>
```

You could have a mapping to toggle `list` (stole this one from [tpope's unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired)):

```
nnoremap yol setlocal list!
```

`nnoremap` is good practice: you only need this function in normal mode (`n`), and don't want it to be recursive (`nore`).

Answer (score 0):

```
function! SpecialKeyWarning()
    set list
    set listchars=tab:→\ ,space:·,nbsp:␣,eol:¶
    highlight SpecialKey ctermfg=blue ctermbg=red guifg=blue guibg=red
endfunction
map <f5> :call SpecialKeyWarning()<CR>

function! SpecialKeyNormal()
    set  nolist 
endfunction
map <f6> :call SpecialKeyNormal()<CR>
```

Comment: That's not really what you asked in your question. But if it works for you, you can simplify everything: leave `set listchar...` and `highlight SpecialKey...` in your vimrc out of a function and simple use `nnoremap <f5> :set list!<CR>` to toggle the `list` option with only one key. (Also you should always use mode specific map commands like `nmap` or `imap` and unless you know what you are doing you should always use the non recursive version of map commands i.e. `nnoremap` and `inoremap`)

Answer (score 0):

```
set listchars=tab:→\ ,space:·,nbsp:␣,eol:¶
highlight SpecialKey ctermfg=blue ctermbg=red guifg=blue guibg=red
nnoremap <f5> :set list!<CR>
```

Comment: It would be great if you'd provide a bit of explanation as for why this solution works (even if this is quite obvious).